# Is there any way to tell rabbitMQ resend an unacknowledged message to a worker?

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp

Hi there i have a **rabbitMQ** queue and just **one worker** to handle queued messages. I want to know is there any way to tell rabbitMQ if a message is unacknowledged send it again to worker periodically.

Very thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RabbitMQ will consider a message delivered and not yet acknowledged as being consumed.  You cannot enforce it to be re-delivered as long as the consumer which fetched it does not close the channel or reject the message via the `basic.reject` [AMQP](https://www.rabbitmq.com/specification.html) method.

You can read more about publish/delivery confirmation in the [documentation](https://www.rabbitmq.com/confirms.html).